# 2SLS vs OLS Efficiency Question

Tags: least-squares, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I'm doing some studying for finals and I'm wondering what would happen in a case like this.

With the following model
$y_t = x_t * \beta + \epsilon_t$

Say you had two IV's, $a_t$ and $b_t$. In reality, $a_t$ = $x_t$ but you do not know this. So you estimate $y_t$ using $b_t$ as an IV, where $b_t$ ~ iid. $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Would the resulting estimator then be as asymptotically efficient as OLS?

Comment: If you use only one instrument $b_t$ we can't compare the asymptotic variance to OLS without knowing more. If you use both instruments, the first stage fitted values exactly equal $x_t$ (because $a_t$ is $x_t$) so the second stage is numerically equivalent to OLS.